# How to calculate aggregate percentage in a dataframe grouped by a value in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, key-value

I am new to python and I am trying to understand how to work with aggregating data and manipulation.

I have a dataframe:

```
df3
Out[122]: 
                     SBK               SSC  CountRecs
0                    99                 22      9
1                    99                 12      10
2                    99                121      11
3                    99                138      12
4                    99                123      8
                ...                ...        ...
160247              184               1318          1
160248              394               2659          1
160249              412                757          1
160250              357               1312          1
160251              202                106          1
```

I want to understand in the entire data frame, what percentage of CountRecs for each SBK.
For example, in this case, I want to understand 80618 is what % of the summation total number of SBK's with 99. in this case it is 9/50 * 100. But I want this to be done automated for all rows. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to group by the column you want,
2. marge by the grouped column.
   2.1 you can change the name of the new column.
3. add the percentage column.

   ```
    a = df3.merge(pd.DataFrame(df3.groupby('SBK' ['CountRecs'].sum()),on='SBK')
    df3['percent'] = (a['CountRecs_x']/a['CountRecs_y']) *100
    df3
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for Series with same size like original DataFrame filled by counts, so you can divide original column:

```
df3['percent'] = df3['CountRecs'] / df3.groupby('SBK')['CountRecs'].transform('sum') * 100
print (df3)
        SBK   SSC  CountRecs  percent
0        99    22          9     18.0
1        99    12         10     20.0
2        99   121         11     22.0
3        99   138         12     24.0
4        99   123          8     16.0
160247  184  1318          1    100.0
160248  394  2659          1    100.0
160249  412   757          1    100.0
160250  357  1312          1    100.0
160251  202   106          1    100.0
```